# Rails - Outputting content, sanitize or <%=h?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

I recently made a small rails3 app to convert an old cms written in another language. After migrating the content I am having problems outputting content from the database.

The @content.desc field sometimes has html. Currently the only way I could get it to work was:

```
<%= sanitize content.desc %>
```

But is this the best way? When I use `<%=h @content.desc %>` I can see the html tags still. When I use `<%= simple_format @content.desc %>` I get wicked spacing.

Is there a definitive guide somewhere where I can see all of the options while outputting content? I've tried to search but can't turn anything up (rails newb, i know).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any string not marked as "safe" will be HTML-escaped by default in Rails 3. Some methods, such as `sanitize`, `h`, `link_to` and many other helpers return safe strings, thus allowing them to be written literally. See [this blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) for more info.

If you know for sure that the HTML contained in `@content.desc` is safe, you can mark it as such yourself like so: `<%= @content.desc.html_safe %>`.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3 has changed HTML sanitisation to be enabled by default. If you're *sure* that the string you're rendering is safe, you can use

`<%= @content.desc.html_safe! %>`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you shouldn't have to sanitize the content before displaying it, as Rails 3 does that by default. More info here: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Comment: It doesn't actually sanitize it, it HTML-escapes it. [`sanitize` is different](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize).